# Better python code for reduce memory usage?

Tags: python, performance, google-colaboratory, haversine

I have a data frame of about 19 million rows, which 4 of the variables are latitudes & longitudes. I create a function to calculate distance of latitudes & longitudes with help of python [haversine](https://pypi.org/project/haversine/) package.

```
# function to calculate distance of 2 coordinates

def measure_distance(lat_1, long_1, lat_2, long_2):

    coordinate_start = list(zip(lat_1, long_1))
    coodrinate_end = list(zip(lat_2, long_2))
    
    distance = haversine_vector(coordinate_start, coodrinate_end, Unit.KILOMETERS)

    return distance
```

I use magic command `%%memit` to measure memory usage to perform the calculation. On average, memory usage is between 8 - 10 GB. I run my work on Google Colab which has 12GB RAM, as a result, sometime the operation hit the limit of runtime and restart.

```
%%memit

measure_distance(df.station_latitude_start.values, 
                 df.station_longitude_start.values, 
                 df.station_latitude_end.values, 
                 df.station_longitude_end.values)

peak memory: 7981.16 MiB, increment: 5312.66 MiB
```

Is there a way to optimise my code?

Comment: How much memory (dimensions as well as bytes) is used by your input dataframe, and how much memory do you expect the output distance array would take up? It could be possible that your dataset is just too big for your machine to afford making copies of the data during computation. The `list(zip...` lines definitely copies your data, and it's possible the `haversine_vector` function makes temporary intermediate arrays.

Comment: with `.info()`, I can tell the data frame is using about 600 MB memory. I don't have specific expectation, just want to find out memory usage for this command when I see Google Colab crashes. I tried to create `coordinate_start` & `coordinate_end` then use them in `haversine` and each of these operations use as much memory as 8GB. So I decided to see any difference if I wrap everything in function.  End up, memory usage is almost same with/without function. My goal is to reduce memory usage so Google Colab won't crashes.

Comment: 600 MB is certainly big, but 12 GB can afford 20 copies (well less than that because memory is also used for other things). I'm suspecting that `haversine_vector` is just making too many temporary arrays.

Try looking at how much memory is used if you don't run the `haversine_vector` function (comment it out by typing `#` in front). The docs suggest it returns a numpy array of distances with the same length as its inputs, so you could return a dummy value of `distance = numpy.zeros(len(coordinate_start))`. If the memory usage plummets, then we know for sure it's `haversine_vector`'s fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** use *Numpy* and compute the result by *chunk*.

The amount of memory taken by the CPython interpreter is expected regarding the big input size.

Indeed, CPython stores values in list using *references*. On a 64-bit system, references takes 8 bytes and basic types (float and small integers) take usually 32 bytes. A tuple of two floats is a complex type that contains the size of the tuple as well as *references* of the two floats (not values themselves). Its size should be close to 64 bytes. Since you have 2 lists containing 19 million of (reference of) float pairs and 4 list containing 19 million of (reference of) floats, the resulting memory taken should be about `4*19e6*(8+32) + 2*19e6*(8+64) = 5.7 GB`. Not to mention that Haversine can make some internal copies and the result take some space too.

If you want to reduce the memory usage, then **use Numpy**. Indeed, float Numpy arrays store values in a much more compact way (no references, no internal tag). You can replace the list of tuple by a `N x 2` Numpy 2D array. The resulting size should be about `4*19e6*8 + 2*19e6*(8*2) = 1.2 GB`. Moreover, the computation will be much faster Haversine use Numpy internally. Here is an example:

```py
import numpy as np
 
# Assume lat_1, long_1, lat_2 and long_2 are of type np.array.
# Use np.array(yourList) if you want to convert it.
def measure_distance(lat_1, long_1, lat_2, long_2):
    coordinate_start = np.column_stack((lat_1, long_1))
    coordinate_end = np.column_stack((lat_2, long_2))
    return haversine_vector(coordinate_start, coordinate_end, Unit.KILOMETERS)
```

The above code is about **25 time faster**.

---

If you want to reduce even more the memory usage, you can **compute the coordinate by chunk** (for example 32K values) and then concatenate the output chunks. You can also use **single precision** numbers rather than double precision if you do not care too much about the accuracy of the computed distances.

Here is an example of how to compute the result by chunk:

```py
def better_measure_distance(lat_1, long_1, lat_2, long_2):
    chunckSize = 65536
    result = np.zeros(len(lat_1))
    for i in range(0, len(lat_1), chunckSize):
        coordinate_start = np.column_stack((lat_1[i:i+chunckSize], long_1[i:i+chunckSize]))
        coordinate_end = np.column_stack((lat_2[i:i+chunckSize], long_2[i:i+chunckSize]))
        result[i:i+chunckSize] = haversine_vector(coordinate_start, coordinate_end, Unit.KILOMETERS)
    return result
```

On my machine, using *double* precision, the above code takes about 800 MB while the initial implementation take 8 GB. Thus, **10 times less memory**! It is also still **23 times faster**! Using *simple* precision, the above code takes about 500 MB, so **16 times less memory, and it is 48 times faster**!

Comment: TQ @Jérôme Richard for your advice. By using `np.column_stack`, the operation is optimized with `peak memory: 2806.70 MiB, increment: 0.02 MiB` and calculation completed within 5 seconds. It is really amazing!! Can you please further elaborate on the `chunk` method with sample codes?

Comment: I updated the answer to add more information about this method and my results ;) .

Comment: Thanks again. I will spend some time to study this method.